TestNG Parallel execution in Jenkins Selenium Grid
I am executing my selenium testng tests in parallel in my Jenkins server which is on a VM.
I am using selenium standalone grid having Max.Concurrency as 4.
My tests run perfectly fine in my local in parallel. But in jenkins I see that the browser just opens and closes and build fails immediately.
Below is my surefire plugin
Below is my xml structure
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>3.1.2</version>
  <configuration>
    <parallel>methods</parallel>
    <threadCount>2</threadCount>
    <suiteXmlFiles>
      <suiteXmlFile>${suiteXmlFile}</suiteXmlFile>
    </suiteXmlFiles>
    <skipTests>false</skipTests>
  </configuration>
</plugin>

This is how I start my selenium grid
nohup java -jar selenium-server-4.8.3.jar hub & nohub java -jar selenium-server-4.8.3.jar node &
I have tried to pass parallel and threadcount variables both from testng.xml and also surefire plugin. Neither of them are working in Jenkins
I am getting a null pointer exception for webdriver instance.

Please edit your question and add details around what your code looks like and the stacktrace of the error. That will give more context to what can be the issue
